# How to retrieve records grouped by distinct atribute values as hash(-like)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I am using `rails 4.2.x` and `simple_form` and my aim is to create a select-box with optgroups, where the unique values of a models attribute are the groups.

A simplified version of my model looks like this (kind is an `integer` column in database table):

```
# app/models/technology.rb
class Technology < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum kind: {
    programming_language: 1, framework: 2, skill: 3, application: 4, technology: 5
  }
end
```

For example, I have three technologies:

```
t1 = Technology.create!(name: "Ruby", kind: :programming_language)
t2 = Technology.create!(name: "Java", kind: :programming_language)
t3 = Technology.create!(name: "Ruby on Rails", kind: :framework)
```

and I want a query that results in:

```
groups = Technology.magical_query(:kind)
# groups => { programming_language: [t1, t2],
#             framework: [t3] }
```

The returned value does not have to contain an `Array` or a `Hash`, a Relation will do fine.

I assumed `ActiveRecord` would make it easy to construct such a query (probably with a `group(:kind)` - Statement, but alone it does not help me as I cannot - or do not know how to - iterate over the groups and get its 'entries').

There are non-magic "workarounds" or alternative patterns:

- First fetching the distinct values of an attribute (in my example it is an enum, so I actually know the values beforehand), then firing separate queries and glueing them togeter. But I would like to avoid multiple database-hits.

Code sample:

```
Technology.kinds.map do |kind|
  [kind, Technology.where(kind: kind)]
end.to_h
```

- Model TechnologyKind as an own entity.

What is the pure `ActiveRecord` way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `group` method from `ActiveRecord` is an equivalent to SQL `GROUP BY` and it is used with the aggregate functions (like `sum` or `count`). As far as I understood, you don't want to use the aggregate functions.

You can achieve what you want by using [Rails group_by method](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by). It returns a `Hash`, so you can easily iterate through it.

Your code should look like this:

```
groups = Technology.all.group_by(&:kind)
programming_languages = groups['programming_language']
```

So `programming_languages` stores `[t1, t2]` from your example.

Comment: But for databases with hundreds of thousands of records I guess it is best to get a sum only not a hash of values. Any idea how to do that using group_by and sum?

Comment: Could you provide more context - I am not sure what your problem is.  You probably need to use the `group` and `sum` methods from `ActiveRecord`, if you want to get the sum.